# Voltage Divider to Power LED

Tags: led, current, resistors, voltage-divider, homework

I want to construct a voltage divider according to this schematic. I want to set the R1, R2, and R3 voltages to power a LED with a forward voltage of 3,5V and a forward current of 25mA. How should I think?

Updated to add:
The full question is the following:

> You want to show that a motor is running by lighting an LED. The motor
> drives at 12 V and 0.8A, while the LED drives at a forward voltage of
> Udiod = 3.5 V and an Idiode = 25 mA according to the data below. To
> get the right voltage across the LED, a voltage divider is used. A
> rule of thumb is that the current through the voltage divider is 10
> times as large as that which passes over the consumer (LED)

[image: The circuit I where I want to set the R1, R2, and R3 values.]

Comment: You don't need R1 or R2. Tons of guides online explaining how to calculate the value of R3. Tried google?

Comment: Why do you need a voltage divider?

Comment: The assignment I have states that I should set the values of R1, R2, and R3. I have not made this schematic.

Comment: Is there any way to make this using values of R1 and R2 that are not zero?

Comment: R2 cannot be zero. Not needing R2 does not set it to zero.

Comment: That's just poor teaching then. Or we're missing some context.

Comment: Missing some context is the likely thing but you can't rule out incompetent teaching.

Comment: This is what the question says: You want to show that a motor is running by lighting an LED. The motor drives at 12 V and 0.8A, while the LED drives at a forward voltage of Udiod = 3.5 V and an Idiode = 25 mA according to the data below. To get the right voltage across the LED, a voltage divider is used. A rule of thumb is that the current through the voltage divider is 10 times as large as that which passes over the consumer (LED)

Comment: That's poor teaching then. Set R1 to zero, R2 to infinity, and calculate a suitable value for R3 to get the right **current** through the LED. You could make R1 and R2 a voltage divider carrying 10 x the LED current, but nowhere would you do that for this purpose outside of being told to. It's like being told to cook 10 eggs, then throw 9 away and eat the remaining one for breakfast. It's possible, but there's no point.

Comment: Homework assignment. And even bad one, that is not how it is usually done, but given the assignment, use the values given. It says use ten times in the divider than in the load. You should first at least try to solve it and then ask if you are stuck.

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. Ask your instructor if the assignment is unclear.

Comment: It just occured to me that based on the schematics given, R3 can't be calculated. R1 and R2 can. Unless there is and error in the drawing of course and the given LED forward voltage is 3.5V instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a homework problem so I will only point towards an approach...

Homework problems are usually constructed around some specific teaching point, in this case I think they're trying to teach "*A rule of thumb is that the current through the voltage divider is 10 times as large as that which passes over the consumer*". That is in fact a good rule of thumb. So that sets the bias current needed through R1 and R2, based on how much current needs to drive the LED. (As a side note: be sure to think about how much *power* will be lost in R1 and R2.)

This is a very bad circuit for driving a motor, because it lacks the freewheeling diode to protect against the voltage surge which happens when the motor turns off and the rotor is still spinning. If you haven't learned about inductors yet, be warned, inductors respond to a change in current, with an opposing change in their terminal voltage. So switching off an inductor causes a sharp change in voltage. How much depends on how rapidly the current is changed. But this is beyond the scope of this homework problem. Just keep in mind this isn't a real motor driving circuit...

This is also a very bad circuit for driving an LED, because the voltage divider R1/R2 already performs the role of limiting the LED drive current, so R3 is not really necessary. Most likely R3 was put there because of a "design rule" that an LED always requires a series resistor (not strictly true BTW, just a good rule of thumb). R3 just adds a needless degree of freedom which isn't required in this case, and just gets in the way of solving the problem

If I were choosing the series resistor for an LED, I would need to know the LEDs operating forward voltage \$V_{f}\$ and forward current \$I_{f}\$, and since I know both the voltage at each end of the resistor and the current through the resistor, I would just apply Ohm's law. **But, as noted in a comment by @Justme, this badly designed circuit has an error.** As drawn, they've specified Udiod=3.5V, which is apparently also meant to be the forward voltage of the LED. So there is no voltage drop left for R3. Either that, or you're expected to arbitrarily choose the voltage at both ends of R3, and the circuit would be undecidable. As a practical matter, 3.5V is a credible value for an LED forward voltage (red LEDs are usually about 1.5V@10mA, other colors often require higher forward voltage); so my best guess is that R3 is a mistake and should be replaced by a direct "short" connection to LED1.

I don't know whether you've learned Thevenin/Norton equivalent sub-circuits yet, but just FYI the 12V voltage source with resistive divider R1/R2, is equivalent to a voltage source of 12V x R2 / (R1 + R2) with a series resistor of (R1 parallel with R2). So the R1/R2 voltage divider's equivalent parallel resistance is what satisfies the design rule of connecting a resistor in series with an LED to limit its current.

R3 just adds a needless degree of freedom which isn't required in this case, and just gets in the way of solving the problem. So my approach would be to set R3=0 and then determine R1/R2 based on the required voltage and current to the LED. However @Neil_UK in the comments suggested another approach which discards R1/R2 by setting R1=0 and R2=not installed, and then determines a value for R3 using the approach I described earlier, 12V on one end of R3, 3.5V on the other end of R3, and applying Ohm's law. Both are valid approaches to this badly constructed homework problem.

A much better textbook for learning analog electronics is The Art of Electronics (Horowiz and Hill, Cambridge University press, ISBN 0-521-37095-7).

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is wrong. The teacher is wrong. The other people commenting are wrong. The original poster is also wrong (because OP said Vf = 3.5V, which it is not).

It is a shoddy problem but it can be solved. Start by writing in the things you know. Udiod and Idiod are given. The forward voltage of the diode is NOT ACTUALLY GIVEN AND NOT KNOWN. Udiod is NOT the forward voltage of the diode (according to the schematic).

So we want Idiod to be 25mA. We want the current through R1 and R2 to be 10x Idiod. This means the following:

Vin / (R1 + R2) = 10 * Idiod

That can be used to solve for the sum of R1 and R2. We also have the voltage divider equation:

Udiod = Vin * (R2 / (R1 + R2))

It is up to you to manipulate the two equations to get an answer.

We have no way to know what R3 is. We just know that R3 * Idiod = 3.5 - Vf. That could be submitted as an answer, under the circumstances (after solving for R3).

In reality, all we need is one resistor and one LED. But since the professor is asking for a voltage divider and saying that the current should be 10x the consumer, what I have outlined is the only way that makes sense.

It would be worthwhile to discuss with the professor how R1 could just be a short, R2 could be an open, and R3 alone could set the current in the LED.